# Is there a way to merge identical excel tabs into one dataframe using python?

Tags: python, excel, merge, aggregate

I'm extremely new to python, and am having some issues attempting to merge identical excel tabs (same column labels and data) into a aggregated tab.

I've been looking through various resources, and this [link](https://gist.github.com/anderser/1276531) appears to be the best resource, but it doesn't quite mesh with the way I've been shown.

I am interested in seeing if there is any part of the code below that is viable when attempting this merge, and by extension, I'm interested in seeing if there are any other resources out there that may be a potential solution or mirror the style of coding that I've been taught.

Thank You!

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np


#Define Dataframes
df_ui = pd.read_excel('U:/ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='UreaImports')
df_ue = pd.read_excel('U:/ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='UreaExports')
df_uani = pd.read_excel('U://ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='UANImports')
df_uane = pd.read_excel('U://ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='UANExports')
df_nh3i = pd.read_excel('U://ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='NH3Imports')
df_nh3e = pd.read_excel('U://ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Trade Shell.xlsx', sheet_name='NH3Exports')

#Merge Dataframes
df_raw = pd.merge(df_ui,df_ue,df_uani,df_uane,df_nh3i,df_nh3e)


# Sends all data tables to an excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('U:/ABA/Data/Trade/GTIS/GTIS Python Build.xlsx', 
engine='xlsxwriter')

df_raw.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='raw')


writer.save()
```